# First element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why do indexes in arrays always start with 0? Does it have something to do with binary? For example:

```
var myArray = [5,6,7,8];
```

To access the number 5, you would have to say

```
myArray[0]
```

But why?

No, I don't have a real problem. As you can evidently tell I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: Welcome to the field of computer science.

Comment: Do you have an actual problem to be solved or is this just for educational reasons?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering and http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html

Comment: From the wiki link: "The Swiss Federal Railways number certain classes of rolling stock from zero". I suppose that's as good a reason as any ;)

Comment: That wikipedia page is excellant! I suggest that over many other possible readings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this has been asked an answered a hundred times, but I'll bite.

One way of looking at the "index" or "key" is as an "offset".

`myArray` essentially acts as a *pointer* to the first item in a series of items. Specifically, it points to the number "5" in memory. So when you say `myArray[1]` it's like saying "the location of the first element in `myArray` plus 1 item over", thus you would be jumping over the first element.

In C, when you write `*myArray` (pointer dereference) it actually gives you back the first element.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int myArray[] = {5,6,7,8};
    printf("%d",*myArray); // prints "5", equivalent to myArray[0]
    printf("%d",*(myArray+1)); // prints "6", equivalent to myArray[1]
    return 0;
}
```

There are [more practical](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) reasons than "that's the way computers work" too.

Answer (score 1):

nice blog about the historical reasons: http://developeronline.blogspot.fi/2008/04/why-array-index-should-start-from-0.html

Answer (score 0):

It's basic computer science stuff, which harkens back to the day when memory was so limited, everything started with 0s and not 1s because if you started at 0 you could count up to ten total numbers in a single digit.

You're clearly new to this, trust me, from now on, you'll be counting 0 , 1 , 2 , 3!

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia gives us this explanation:

> **Index origin**
>
> Some languages, such as C, provide only zero-based array types, for
>   which the minimum valid value for any index is 0. This choice is
>   convenient for array implementation and address computations. With a
>   language such as C, a pointer to the interior of any array can be
>   defined that will symbolically act as a pseudo-array that accommodates
>   negative indices. This works only because C does not check an index
>   against bounds when used. Other languages provide only one-based array
>   types, where each index starts at 1; this is the traditional
>   convention in mathematics for matrices and mathematical sequences. A
>   few languages, such as Pascal, support n-based array types, whose
>   minimum legal indices are chosen by the programmer. The relative
>   merits of each choice have been the subject of heated debate.
>   **Zero-based indexing has a natural advantage to one-based indexing in avoiding off-by-one or fencepost errors**. See comparison of
>   programming languages (array) for the base indices used by various
>   languages.

[Read more about arrays here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type)

[Read more about off-by-one and fencepost errors here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, like many other languages, arrays always start at index zero, but it's not that way in all languages.

In Pascal, for example, you define the lower and upper boundary, so you can start an array at index three:

```
var myArray: Integer[3..6];
```

It's most common to start arrays at zero, because that's most efficient when you access the items. If you start at any other index, that value has to be subtracted when the address where the item is stored is calculated. That extra calculation wouldn't be an issue today, but back when languages like C was constructed it surely was.

(Well, arrays in Javascript is actually accessed completely different from most other languages, but it uses zero based indexes because most similar languages, where the inspiration comes from, do.)